# Variadic template argument expansion in partial template specialization

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template (the non-specialized version is disabled for testing purposes):

```
template <typename...>
std::enable_if_t<false> S;
```

And i want to partially specialize it, but for some reason it does not work (Visual Studio 2017 RC: `error C2275: 'x': illegal use of this type as an expression`, `error C3544: '<unnamed-symbol>': parameter pack expects a type template argument`):

```
template<typename... x>
int S<int(x)...> = sizeof...(x);
```

What i want to achieve can be approximated with something like this:

```
template<typename x1>
int S<int(x1)> = 1;

template<typename x1, typename x2>
int S<int(x1), int(x2)> = 2;

template<typename x1, typename x2, typename x3>
int S<int(x1), int(x2), int(x3)> = 3;

//etc
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: `int(x1)` is a function returning `int`, and taking one parameter of type `x1`

Comment: would it work with `std::function`?

Comment: I found ways which works with gcc but not with clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47df719a6bf1f0cf).

Comment: Very interesting, this seems to work:
`template<typename... x>
int S<std::function<int(x)>...> = sizeof...(x);`

Comment: And one that both accept: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96e50f43e57c2280). :)

Comment: You may then use some `identity_t<int(x)>` instead of `std::function<int(x)>` to have your desired type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version works on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

The trick is to hide `int(T)` in its own custom type:

```
template <typename T>
using FInt = int(T);

template <typename ... Ts>
int S = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Ts) >= 0)>{};

template<typename ... Ts>
int S<FInt<Ts> ...> = sizeof...(Ts);
```

Comment: I haven't really looked at the *question*, but re the answer, (a) <del>how can `int(T)` be valid code</del> OH it's a function type, (b) wont' `sizeof...(Ts) >= 0` always be true?,  and (c) won't that `{}` be instantiating a `void` type, which is only allowed in a `return` expression of a `void` function? I guess it's time to look at the question. But I'm so far perplexed.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: OP wants to enable template variable only for one specialization. If that was a function, I would use `= delete` for the general case, but here it is indeed a hack/work-around to allow compilation on both msvc, gcc and clang. (a) yes, it is the function type OP wants for the specialization. (b) always true, but depends of `Ts`. (c) I indeed want an error in the instantiation of that template.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, upvoted as it looks like a good answer. :)

Comment: Very nice workaround. So it seems like the syntax/grammar is the part causing the problem? C++ grammar is really quirky sometimes. I guess the next step would be looking into the standard, and figuring out what the correct behavior should be. Thanks for the answer :)